# Is it possible to remove touchability from within an extension of surfaceview?

Tags: java, android

I'm working to develop UI elements to be used by another team.  I'm doing some drawing on a canvas, but parts of it are transparent.  I'm hoping to make those parts untouchable from the main activity without them having to write extra code- so, if they implement an onTouchListener, it checks the UI element first to see if the touch is within its touchable area.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
public class Indicator extends SurfaceView implements OnTouchListener {

public Indicator(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    InitializeCalculations();
}
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    if (arg1.isWithinTouchableArea)
    {
        Log.d("Indicator","Outside touched!");
        return false;
    }
    Log.d("Indicator","Inside touched!");
    return true;
}
```

This works fine if no touchlistener is defined from the fragment in which the view is present, but if user defines their own touchlistener, this one is not called first (as expected).  Is there a way to modify the order of touchlistener checks, or to otherwise change the touchable area of this view without writing any code from the calling activity or fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `setOnTouchListener`. In its code, call the `super.setOnTouchListener` method passing in a new `OnTouchListener` which executes your touch checks and then executes the `onTouch` method of the `OnTouchListener` passed as a parameter to your overriden `setOnTouchListener`. Finally, make the `setOnTouchListener` final, as it cannot be overridden by subclasses.